# Addition in Conditional in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to check for optional parameters within the flow of a bash script but keep getting an error. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
# Do additional database import if needed
if ( $# == ( $minNumOfParams + 1 ) ) ; then
    mysql -u $newDBUsername -p$newDBPassword $newDBName < $databaseExport2
fi
```

The error I am getting is:

```
/bin/bash: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: line 27: `   if ( 13 == ( 12 + 1 ) ) ; then'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [bash arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) for your comparison

```
if (( $# == $minNumOfParams + 1 )) ; then
```

Comment: Thanks, I come from a PHP background so BASH is always getting me.

Answer (score 0):

i think you may should try  the following :

`if [[ $# -eq $minNumOfParams+1 ]]; then
    mysql -u $newDBUsername -p$newDBPassword $newDBName < $databaseExport2
fi`

Comment: Fine to do the test in `[[]]`, but you still can't do math this way. Can do `[[ $# -eq $((minNumOfParams+1)) ]]` instead.